# How can I convert long float to string in PHP?

Tags: php, string, long-integer, string-conversion

I have very long float 0.000000000000000000000000000001

Aтв I need to get hash from STRING '0.000000000000000000000000000001'!

Because

```
hash('sha224', 0.000000000000000000000000000001); //2121895602ff05385d872035b131385bfb69d19bf4bf266abc3aaa9d
```

But

```
hash('sha224', '0.000000000000000000000000000001'); //f764c4d0e89a57e2e6c3fa04badb6d25c01a096a8c277126063bfb11
```

Example

```
$nm=0.000000000000000000000000000001;
$nm3=(string)$nm;
echo hash('sha224', $nm3); //2121895602ff05385d872035b131385bfb69d19bf4bf266abc3aaa9d
```

is not working.
What can I do?
Thanks.

Comment: `var_dump($nm3);` string(7) "1.0E-30"

Comment: I know about it. What can I do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this works

```
<?php
$nm=0.000000000000000000000000000001;


echo hash('sha224',sprintf('%.30f',$nm)); 
//f764c4d0e89a57e2e6c3fa04badb6d25c01a096a8c277126063bfb11

?>
```